# On a topological space, can the limit of sequences' limitations be rewritten into the limitation of a subsequence in the original sequences?

Tags: general-topology

Considering a group of sequences $\{x_{1,n}\}, \{x_{2,n}\},\{x_{3,n}\}\cdots$ on a topological space $X$, whose limitations are $x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, can we find a subsequence $\{x_n'\}$consists of the items of $\{x_{i,n}\},i=1,2,3,\cdots$, whose limitation happens to be $x$ ?

The answer is obvious on first countable spaces, but on general topological spaces, it is very difficult to prove or deny the existence of such sequence.

Comment: "limitation" should be "limit".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Arens Space (S125 of pi-Base)](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000156). This is exactly an example of a space $\{x_{i,n}:0<  i<\omega,0 < n<\omega\}\cup\{x_n:0 < n<\omega\}\cup\{x\}$ with the properties you ask for.

Given $0 < i_n<\omega$ for each $0 < n<\omega$, consider the set $\{x_{i,n}:i_n< i<\omega,0 < n<\omega\}\cup\{x_n:0 < n<\omega\}\cup\{x\}$. This is a neighborhood of $x$ which misses every $x_n'=x_{i_n,n}$. Thus the desired subsequence cannot be found in this space.

This can happen because the [Arens space is not Fréchet Urysohn](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000156/properties/P000080), even though it's [sequential](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000156/properties/P000079).

Answer (score 0):

For a counterexample in the area of analysis, consider the space $L([0,1])$ of Lipschitz functions on $[0,1]$, given the topology of point-wise convergence with bounded Lipschitz constant (which actually implies uniform convergence by [Arzelà-Ascoli](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem)). More precisely, a set is defined to be closed in this topology if it includes all sequential limit points under this notion of convergence.

Then let $s_n$ denote the saw-tooth functions $s_n(x)=d(x,S_n)$, where $S_n=\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\cdots,1\}$.

Now let $f_{i,n}(x)=is_n(x)+\frac{x}{i}$.  Then certainly each sequence $\{f_{i,n}\}$ converges to $f_i(x):=\frac{x}{i}$, with Lipschitz constant bounded by $i+\frac{1}{i}$, and these in turn converge to $0$ with Lipschitz constant bounded by $1$, yet there is no sequence $f_{i_k,n_k}$ that converges to $0$ as $k\to \infty$ with bounded Lipschitz constant.